# For iOS projects in Xcode, why is the test target set to build by default on Run?

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, build-process, target

We were running into issues trying to add a test target to a project we inherited. The test target was working, however Running the app would always fail due to an error in the test target. We were puzzled by this and eventually found a boolean setting in the scheme that was on by default:

[image]

In the image, I unchecked it, but the test target for Run had a checkmark in it. Removing the checkmark made everything work again.

Why would Apple want Running your application to build your tests also? This makes us think there might be consequences we should be aware of.

Comment: No one here can tell you why Apple sets up a default. If you want to know this, ask Apple. It's not a Stack Overflow question. - Having said that, it does make sense that your tests should not get in a state where you can't build them, so it's reasonable to build the tests when you build-and-run your app. After all, they are not _running_ the tests - they are just making sure they compile. You would do better to put your attention on why your tests can't compile rather than avoiding the issue by unchecking that box.

Comment: Good point, i can direct this question to Apple. To your second point, the tests compile and run fine. But don't only when Running the app.

Comment: But what I'm saying is: that's wrong and you need to think about why it is, not hide it from yourself by unchecking that checkbox. And I can give you a start: it probably has something to do with the difference between your Debug config and your QA config, which for some reason you are using when you Run.

Answer (score 4):

The problem, judging by your screen shot, is that this scheme uses the QA configuration for the Run action, whereas it uses the Debug configuration for the Test action. Thus, things work one way when you do a Test build and a different way when you do a Run build.

Comment: The same thing happens on Debug scheme. I just happened to take the screenshot with QA.  I have combed through the build settings and don't see why this is happening.

Comment: Well, when the tests don't compile, what happens? I mean, you say "an error" - so _what_ error? I mean, "why this is happening" sounds to me like the really interesting part of the part of the problem, so personally I think that's what you should be asking about and describing. :)